# Forms in oracle apps

Tags: oracleforms

Am new to oracle apps,tried to implement a small logic to transfer the records from staging table to permanent table on clicking transfer button in form.After updating/inserting the data in perm table,transfer flag in staging table should be updated to 'Y'.
In the form I am taking staging table columns as a datablock.

sample Code:

```
GO_BLOCK('stg_datablock');
  first_record;
Loop
--Insert/Update on perm table
--Now try to update staging table transfer_flag to Y to indicate the record has been transferred to perm.

    update staging_table set TRANSFER_FLAG='Y' WHERE col1=:stg_datablock.col1 and col2=:stg_datablock.col2;
    EXIT
    WHEN :system.last_record = 'TRUE';
      next_record;
    END LOOP;
```

But I tried to implement this,it took long time to execute.Could anyone please suggest me the reason for poor efficiency.Any suggestions wil be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason for the Q.Sorry for creating confusion, i forgot to mention the last command which i have in the code,"commit_form",due to which it took more time to process.I have replaced commit_form() with standard commit,now the execution is as expected.

Thanks,
Likitha

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not recommend to perform any DML sentences within forms, you must create a Program Unit and call a pkg or procedure to your data base and perform those operations.